# How to register an event handler for when an OverlayView is added to the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can I register for an event for when a google.maps.OverlayView instance is added to the map?

Comment: event for what...the map or the OverlayView?

Comment: For the map. For example this can be achieved for `google.maps.ImageMapType` instances by adding an 'insert_at' listener to the map's `overlayMapTypes` collection.